# Check previously visited nodes on cypher

Tags: database, performance, neo4j, cypher

I have a big dataset and I am doing the following query to find paths between two nodes:

```
MATCH (a:Industry{ id:140 }),(b:Industry{ id:386 })
WITH a,b
MATCH p=(a)-[:SELLS*..3]->(b)
return p
```

I heard that cypher does DFS, which is ok for me. But my graph has many loops, so there are many cases when for example a node at (tree)level 3 has a connection with a node at level 1, which results in much more checks than needed.

How can I check if a node has been visited already before visiting it? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I don't know whether cypher does a DFS or not - and you shouldn't know or care either.

One of the big points of advantage with cypher is that it's a declarative graph query language.  That is, you tell it what data you want and it goes and gets it.  You don't have to know or care how, and hopefully with time as a query optimizer gets better, it's going to end up doing it faster than you could have anyway. Contrast this with imperative graph query, which is where you specify *how* you want the data to be fetched.

Cypher generally doesn't retrace paths it's already been over because that wouldn't be efficient, but it might visit certain nodes multiple times depending on the query (i.e. if there are multiple paths through to the same node).

Cypher doesn't provide any features for controlling how the graph traversal happens - hopefully you'll agree with me that this is a feature, not a bug.

If you want fine grained control over how the graph is traversed, what has been seen, or what to do when things are encountered, then I think you want [the java Traversal API](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html).  Among many other options, you can specify BFS/DFS, and you can specify traversal options like "only visit each node once" (no matter what the relationships specify) or the flip, "only visit each relationship once".

Now, to the case of your particular query, if it's returning many more paths than you want, perhaps you need to narrow your query to get rid of the ones you don't want.  You might want to look at [longest path queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764527/how-to-find-all-the-longest-paths-with-cypher-query) for example to get rid of the "shortcut" paths through the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. Let's say, we have 4 nodes: (a), (b), (c), (d). (a) goes to (b), (c), (d). (b) goes to (c), (d). (c) goes to (a), (d). If I don't specify maximum path length, will it go to (a) after visiting (c)?

Comment: My understanding is that cypher traversal avoids cycles, so if you start from a and it gets to c, it won't loop back to a then continue on to b, because that would be a cycle.

Comment: But I'm not sure why you're worrying about this at all to be honest. Cypher is going to try to traverse the minimum necessary to return the result set you want.  If it's returning too much, it's better to ask for less rather than to  worry about how cypher is generating the result set.

Comment: P.S. I agree that it is feature but I dont like that the framework is in java only.

Comment: I cannot know if it returns too much or not as the answers are too many. I am worried about it because the traversal takes nore than 10 seconds which i can't afford.

Comment: If i had control over the traversal I could write my own algorithm optimized for ny problem. Java may be an option bit i may move to another db.

Comment: I don't understand "I cannot know if it returns too much" -- can't you look at your graph, look at the results of your query, and determine exactly this?  If you don't know whether your query is returning too much, again, the problem is in your query - it's essential to understand its results otherwise you'll never be able to rely on it, even if you can control the internals.

Comment: You can look into using Gremlin with Neo4j. My understanding is that it acts as an interface to the Java API, so it gives you better control in certain situations. I would not expect good performance from a query this broad no matter what, though. You should find a way to limit it more.

Comment: Examples would be by fixing your data model so you don't have the same relationship type between so many nodes or adding properties that you can use to limit the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `shortestPath()` in Cypher which is an optimized, bidirectional algorithm. (Or `allShortestPaths()`)

For your example:

```
MATCH (a:Industry{ id:140 }),(b:Industry{ id:386 })
MATCH p=shortestPath((a)-[:SELLS*..3]->(b))
return p
```

Make sure you have an index/constraint for `:Industry(id)`

Comment: Will `allShortestPaths())` find all the paths? From the name of it, it will just find paths of length 2.

Comment: How can I make sure it uses the index, because I deleted the index and tried the same query and the performance was still the same. Is `[:SELLS*..3]` optimized to use indexes?